# iOS Webview: Calling a button action in Webview programmatically

Tags: ios, webview

Say I have a UIwebview which shows a Login screen with username field, password field and a submit button.

Now when the webview is loaded, is it possible that I am able to populate the username and password fields from my code and finally call the submit button action (or say click the Submit button via code) . ?

Please provide some good references/

Answer (score 1):

Use the webview's `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:` to set values using Javascript and even simulate a button press.

```
[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('loginId').value = '%@';document.getElementById('passwordId').value = '%@';document.getElementById('buttonId').click()", username, password]];
```

Make sure to escape the input correctly, or you may break the javascript.